# Could not load Microsoft.Build or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, dependencies, assemblies

I am using the Microsoft.Build framework in a WPF project to build projects during runtime. In my app.config I have specified the following assemblybindings:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Engine" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The following references are in my project file (.csproj):

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Build.15.5.179\lib\net46\Microsoft.Build.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.5.179\lib\net46\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.15.5.179\lib\net46\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.15.5.179\lib\net46\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The NuGet version of the Microsoft.Build packages is 15.5.179. This works fine while running and debugging the project. The packages I have installed are:

- Microsoft.Build
- Microsoft.Build.Framework
- Microsoft.Build.Runtime
- Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core
- Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core

However, I added a Setup Wizard (.vdproj) to my solution and while the detected dependencies for Microsoft.Build.* show up as version 15.1.0.0, when I build the executable, install and then run my application I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

What am I missing..?

**Update:**

Interestingly enough, the MSBuild dll's in the installed application directory are of version 15.5.179 - the NuGet version.

The References tab in my project contains 4 references to versions 15.1.0.0 of:

- Microsoft.Build
- Microsoft.Build.Framework
- Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core
- Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core

Comment: You are missing `Microsoft.Build`. You only got `Microsoft.Build.Framework` which is a different NuGet package

Comment: I added any bindings that I might have been missing (see above), although I get the exact same result.

Comment: Verify all projects' references (in the csproj files) to MSBuild are what you expect them to be. Sounds like one (or more) might be referencing 15.1.  
Also, are you building in a different configuration for the exe? Maybe there's a project that isn't built during debug build that is being built in another configuration (like Release or something) and that's where the 15.1 dependency is coming in?

Comment: Updated my post to include the csproj references. My solution consists of only 2 projects. The actual project and the setup wizard. I don't do anything fancy with configurations.

Comment: Your package source is version 15.5, but the version is specified as 15.1 in your csproj file.  Is that intentional?  The 15.5 package doesn't contain version 15.1

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I can only select 2 specific 15.1.* versions in NuGet, but when I update to those versions, comment out the assembly bindings, refresh the dependencies, rebuild the setup and then test it, it still insists 15.1 cannot be found. When I check the files it does include, for example, version 15.1.584.*

Comment: The setup wizard you're referring to is a 'Visual Studio Installer' Setup project? .vdprog extension?

Comment: It's a .vdproj indeed.

Comment: At a loss on this one :(   I've tried a few things to try and reproduce the issue (mucking about with the Setup, upgrading/downgrading package versions, etc.) and nothing short of deleting the DLL(s) from the installed location gave me any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the version of the Nuget tool installer solved it for me. There seemed to be a version conflict in the Microsoft dependency. Issue disappeared and now builds successfully.

In the `Azure Build Pipeline` > `NuGet tool installer` step, change `Version of NuGet.exe to install` to a newer version, like 5.4.0.

Check Nuget's latest `ReleasedAndBlessed` version at https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json.